# Missing file in Sql Server Compact

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I am getting an error on the creation of database whenever I am creating a database in my application for WIN CE like this:

```
private string _dataSource = "DataSource=data.sdf; Max Buffer Size = 512; Max Database Size = 500";

public void CreateDatabase()
{
    if (File.Exists("data.sdf"))
    {
        return;
    }

    var en = new SqlCeEngine(_dataSource);
    en.CreateDatabase();
}
```

It compiles successfully and when deployed this is the error I get:

`System.TypeLoadException: File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3BE235DF1C8D2AD3`, or one of its dependencies, was not found.

I have already installed the MS Server Compact. I have searched for an answer and came upon this.

You can either remove the reference if you are not using it or deploy the Sql Server Ce cab files for your particular OS and processor type.

> "For only simple develop usage, we just need following CAB to install
> it on target device:
>
> sqlce.dev.ENU.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
>
> This CAB is located in the following directory on my machine :-
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact
> Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\armv4i
>
> Just copy it to target device and click to install it."

I have gotten to this directory ":`\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5` but I do not see the Devices directory and I don't see the armv4i file too.

Answer (score 2):

For all who are in this predicament. Just install the following on your device

```
sqlce.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
sqlce.repl.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
sqlce.dev.ENU.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
```

These are all in the SqlCompactServer in the Programs folder of your development machine so long as you've installed the SqlCompactServer 4.0.